# Kotlin adding a val field to subclass with multiple constructors

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a custom view in Android and I want to add a val field to the constructor, however View contains multiple constructors.

```kotlin
class CustomView : View {

    // I want a `val field: CustomField` in my constructor

    constructor(
        context: Context
    ) : super(context)

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = 0
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    ...
}
```

Kotlin doesn't allow val fields in secondary constructors so I cannot do something like this:

```kotlin
class CustomView : View {

    constructor(
        val field: CustomField,
        context: Context
    ) : super(context)

    constructor(
        val field: CustomField,
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(
        val field: CustomField,
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = 0
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    ...
```

How can I add a val field to the constructors but still extend the multiple constructors of the parent class?

- I've tried adding the val to the secondary constructors, but Kotlin doesn't allow a val on a secondary constructor.
- I've tried creating one primary constructor (the one I'm planning to explicitly use) and ignoring the others. Then Android Studio gives me a Lint warning that I'm missing constructors. (and I would like to know if there's a way to implement them all anyways)
- I've tried adding the field I want as another parameter in the secondary constructor (not a val) and setting it in the secondary constructor body. This leads to the compiler complaining that the val is not initialized if I try to access in an init block and then the Linter still complains I am not implementing the super's constructors

```kotlin
class CustomView : View {

    val field: CustomField

    constructor(
        field: CustomField,
        context: Context
    ) : super(context) { this.field = field }

    ...
```

- If the val I want is a primitive type I could pass it as part of the View's attribute set, however in this case it is not. Also I am hoping for a general Kotlin solution, if it exists.

Comment: I think is not possible because the view, in theory, must be possible to init by XML, and in the XML is not possible to add your custom param... you could create a method to receive your field by param or create custom attributes to pass by xml.

Comment: what  do you want to achieve with val field: CustomField?

Comment: If you use it in XML  layouts, you *have* to have a constructor with parameters solely consisting of Context and AttributeSet. Also, `init` blocks are called before secondary constructors. I think the solution is have an initialization *function* that is called by each constructor, and use `lateinit` as needed. And if this class cannot be instantiated without CustomField, you need to a create default value for it or a way to define it with attributes in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in this way.

You will get error `Property must be initialized or be abstract` because field `myCustomField` must be initialized in every constructor of your class.

Also you cannot use keyword `val` in parameters

```
    class CustomView : View {

        val myCustomField : CustomField

        constructor(customField : CustomField, context: Context?) : super(context){
            this.myCustomField = customField
        }

        constructor(customField : CustomField ,context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs){
            this.myCustomField = customField

        }
        constructor(customField : CustomField, context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
            context,
            attrs,
            defStyleAttr
        ){
            this.myCustomField = customField
        }

        constructor(
            customField : CustomField,
            context: Context?,
            attrs: AttributeSet?,
            defStyleAttr: Int,
            defStyleRes: Int
        ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes){
            this.myCustomField = customField
        }
    }
```

Comment: This plus @Tenfour04 's comment above answers all of my questions, thanks!